# Creating font-family drop-down in Redactor WYSIWYG

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, wysiwyg, text-editor, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to create a dropdown in the [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) editor. The biggest problem is to create a  container around the selected text with the selected font-family.

So far, I have the basic setup for a custom drop-down:

```
$("#text_edit").redactor({
    buttons: ['html', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted', '|', 'table', 'link', '|', 'fontcolor', 'backcolor', '|', 'fontfamily'],
    buttonsCustom: {
        fontfamily: {
            title: "Select Font",
            dropdown: {
                Arial: {
                    title: 'Arial',
                    callback: insertFont
                },
                Georgia: {
                    title: 'Georgia',
                    callback: insertFont
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

function insertFont(obj, e, key)
{
    // wrap selected text in <span> container with style attribute and selected font
}
```

In fact the desired method is very similar to the built-in fontcolor function, which also wraps up the selected text in a  container and assigns the right color style attribute to it.

Comment: I have been looking for this as well, but could not make it work because of a bug in redactor. Have you found any solution? I can change font and font size on all paragraphs but not on selected text though...

Comment: No, I contacted the creators of Redactor but they say it is impossible now. See: http://redactorjs.tenderapp.com/help/discussions/problems/1074-creating-font-family-drop-down.

Due to other requests they say they are working on it :) : http://redactorjs.tenderapp.com/help/discussions/problems/1176-font-support

Answer (score 6):

Improving upon the previous response, here is an implementaion in JQuery which will list all possible web-safe fonts nicely in a dropdown:

```
var oFontMap: {
arial: ["Arial", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"],
arialblack: ["Arial Black", '"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif'],
comicsans: ["Courier New", '"Courier New", Courier, monospace'],
courier: ["Comic Sans", '"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif'],
impact: ["Impact", 'Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif'],
lucida: ["Lucida", '"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif'],
lucidaconsole: ["Lucida Console", '"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace'],
georgia: ["Georgia", "Georgia, serif"],
palatino: ["Palatino Linotype", '"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif'],
tahoma: ["Tahoma", "Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif"],
times: ["Times New Roman", "Times, serif"],
trebuchet: ["Trebuchet", '"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif'],
verdana: ["Verdana", "Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif"] };

//Create the font dropdown
var oFontDropdown = {}
$.each(oFontMap, function(iIndex, oFont){
    var sFontName = oFont[0];
    var sFontFace = oFont[1];
    oFontDropdown[iIndex] = {
        title: "<font face='"+sFontFace+"'>"+sFontName+"</font>",
        callback: function(obj, e, sFont){
            obj.execCommand("fontname", sFontFace);
        }
    }
});

return $(".redactor").redactor({
    focus: true,
    buttonsAdd: ["|", "font"],
    buttonsCustom: {
        font: {
            title: "Advanced Font List",
            dropdown: oFontDropdown
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this, I've solved the same requirement, it in this way, and is running fine here.

```
var setFontFamily;

setFontFamily = function(obj, e, key) {
  if (key === "serif") {
    obj.execCommand("fontname", "Times New Roman");
  }
  if (key === "sans") {
    return obj.execCommand("fontname", "Helvetica");
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  return $(".redactor").redactor({
    focus: true,
    buttonsAdd: ["|", "font"],
    buttonsCustom: {
      font: {
        title: "Advanced List",
        dropdown: {
          serif: {
            title: "Times",
            callback: setFontFamily
          },
          sans: {
            title: "Helvetica",
            callback: setFontFamily
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The setFontFamily function isn't the most beautiful in the world, but it is a proof of concept, then you can see how it define font families.

I'm a rails coder, so I'll leave here the same code, but coffescript version (in case anyone needs it)

```
setFontFamily = (obj, e, key) ->
  obj.execCommand "fontname", "Times New Roman"  if key is "serif"
  obj.execCommand "fontname", "Helvetica"  if key is "sans"

$(document).ready ->
  $(".redactor").redactor
    focus: true
    buttonsAdd: ["|", "font"]
    buttonsCustom:
      font:
        title: "Advanced List"
        dropdown:
          serif:
            title: "Times"
            callback: setFontFamily
          sans:
            title: "Helvetica"
            callback: setFontFamily
```

Answer (score 0):

Redactor released new plugins for that purpose:

```
fontcolor.js, fontsize.js and fontfamily.js
```

When included, you can use them like this:

```
elem.redactor({
      plugins: ['fontcolor', 'fontsize', 'fontfamily']
});
```

See this repository:
https://github.com/johnsardine/redactor-plugins